Using separate_wider_regex for to create a new row for each match in R
I have a dataframe with a long 'comment'-column that includes semi-structered information about the presence of species in several zones for different study sites. The pattern is typically something like the following:



Site
Comment




1
1: species A, species B 2a: species A, species C 4: species A


2
2a: species B 2b: species A 4: species C



Below is a small subset of my data. Please not that it's possible not not all 5 zones are listed. This is when a species was not found for that particular zone. This is not uncommon for Zone 1, but Zone 4 is almost always listed. In other words, I believe I'm dealing with unequal lengths for the matching groups.
I want to use seperate_wider_regex to split the column into two columns and multiple rows. With the end result something like this:



Site
Zone
Species




1
1
species A, species B


1
2a
species A, species C


1
4
species A


2
2a
species B


2
2b
species A


2
4
species C



I can then pivot the dataframe so that each zone gets it's own colomn with pivot_wider. I can match all the zones per row with the following regex: "[1-4][ab]?[:]?" The colon (:) is usually present for the species listings, but not always. I can also match everything between the two patterns, except for zone 4 because there's no pattern to end the match. I thought I could do something like this, but that also doesn't seem to work: ".+?(?=[1-4][ab]?:)|(.*)"
My ideal solution would be using packages from the Tidyverse.
Here's a little subset of my data:
library(tidyr)

sample_df <- structure(list(site = 1:2, comment = c("2a: species A, species B 2b: species A, species C 3: species C, species D 4: species A, species B, species C", 
"2a: species A, species B, species D 2b: species B 3: species C 4: species C, species D, species E"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


You can try
sample_df %>%
  mutate(comment = str_split(comment, "\\s(?=\\S+:)")) %>%
  unnest(comment) %>%
  separate_wider_regex(comment, c(zone = "[^:]+", ":\\s+", species = ".*"))

which gives
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   site zone  species
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 2a    species A, species B
2     1 2b    species A, species C
3     1 3     species C, species D
4     1 4     species A, species B, species C
5     2 2a    species A, species B, species D
6     2 2b    species B
7     2 3     species C
8     2 4     species C, species D, species E


Separate the comments into rows.  Then separate each comment into into a zone and species and trim spaces off the ends.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sample_df %>%
  separate_rows(comment, sep = " (?=[1-4][ab]?[:]?) *") %>%
  separate(comment, c("zone", "species"), sep = ":") %>%
  mutate(species = trimws(species))

giving
# A tibble: 8 × 3
   site zone  species                        
  <int> <chr> <chr>                          
1     1 2a    species A, species B           
2     1 2b    species A, species C           
3     1 3     species C, species D           
4     1 4     species A, species B, species C
5     2 2a    species A, species B, species D
6     2 2b    species B                      
7     2 3     species C                      
8     2 4     species C, species D, species E


nice use of separate_rows, +1! BTW, separate() has been superseded in favour of separate_wider_position() and separate_wider_delim()

I am aware of that but superseded is not deprecated.  superseded will continue to be part of the package so there is no reason not to use it.

yes, that's true, we can keep using it

Here is a possible option which uses str_extract_all and unnest_longer to first create rows for each zone, then uses separate_wider_regex to split the string into the zone and the Species:
sample_df <- structure(list(site = 1:2, comment = c(
  "2a: gele lis, waterzuring 2b: pitrus, witbol 3: witbol, ruw beemd 4: ruw beemd, raaigras, witbol",
  "2a: gele lis, pitrus, mannagras 2b: pitrus 3: gestreepte witbol 4: gestreepte witbol, engels raai, veld/plat beemd"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(tidyverse)

sample_df |>
  mutate(
    comment = str_extract_all(comment, "\\d+[a-z]?:[^\\d]*")
  ) |>
  unnest_longer(comment) |>
  separate_wider_regex(
    comment,
    patterns = c(zone = "^\\d+[a-z]?", ":\\s?", Species = ".*$")
  ) |>
  mutate(
    Species = str_trim(Species)
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>    site zone  Species                                        
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>                                          
#> 1     1 2a    gele lis, waterzuring                          
#> 2     1 2b    pitrus, witbol                                 
#> 3     1 3     witbol, ruw beemd                              
#> 4     1 4     ruw beemd, raaigras, witbol                    
#> 5     2 2a    gele lis, pitrus, mannagras                    
#> 6     2 2b    pitrus                                         
#> 7     2 3     gestreepte witbol                              
#> 8     2 4     gestreepte witbol, engels raai, veld/plat beemd

